# Can a Java web app listen to a tcp port in a local network?

Tags: sockets, jakarta-ee, tcp, port

forgive the triviality of my question. I was asked this question and I wasn't able to find a proper answer so I decided to research this myself and understand. I have `spring` ,`maven` etc background. Supposing I deployed my web app on a `box 192.168.0.10` in my network, can I listen on the port say `9090` of the `192.168.0.10` and do something with it in my application itself running on tomcat7 on the usual port `8080`.

What all this is supposed to do is listen on a port and display a graph on the client side based on the value received.

I was thinking using `maven`, I will have a jar packaged project handling the networking bit and transfer the control to the web app.Event that it's really blur in my mind.

Can anyone clarify things a little bit for me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a different port, effectively your web app is already callable on the port provided by tomcat. You can have various servlets each distinguished by URL, and one can return graphs. There's lots more possibilities, but I don't see any need for another port.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answers. I was more concerned about not having anything tied to tomcat itself to have it case more general .

Comment: If it's a web app, perhaps exploiting JEE or Spring, then it delegates the port stuff to an arbitrary App Server, tomcat or whatever. If you've coded to those portable standards you're not really tied to tomcat as such. I see no value in trying to implement plumbing such as port listening, it's trickier than you might think to make it scalable, so stick with proven solutions like Web Apps.